# Lines after input function is not executing

Tags: python-3.x

I'm in my initial days of python. When I'm trying to print the value which I have inputted, through a print statement its not working. My input is not ending, its taking values but not going to the print statement in the next line.

```
def addition(A,B):
    return A+b
Value1 = input("Enter the Value1:")
print(Value1)
```

Comment: Your IDE should tell you there is an error in the definition of `addition`: `b` does not exist and then indentation is missing.

Comment: Indentation was there; it got wrong while copying here. There was no error while executing, i was able to enter the input, its just not going to next statement, its  allowing me to enter the values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function and also sort out your variable names as they are different and don't conform to PEP8. A final working version would be:

```
def addition(a,b):
    return a+b


value1 = int(input("Enter the Value1:")) # The reason I call int here is input() returns a string.
value2 = int(input("Enter the Value2:"))
print(addition(value1, value2)
```

Comment: thanks.its not executing the line value2 = int(input("Enter the Value2:")) and not asking for the value2.  Value1 is  allowing to input endless multiple lines.

Comment: Where and how are you executing your program? It seems that no EOL is being passed.

Comment: running it in sublime text3 using the build option. python 3.8.0

Comment: Ah, sublime isn't fantastic at inputs. I'd recommend running the program externally. If you are running windows you should be able to do `py file.py` or on linux do `python3 file.py` in the terminal of choice in that directory.

Comment: yeah. through py file.py its working fine. taking two input values and printing them. anything i can do to make it work in sublime ? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not; sublime always has problems of doing this. Personally I would just recommend switching to something like Visual Studio Code.